# About a Possible Decomposition of a Set $E$ of Infinite Measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Can we decompose $m(E)=\infty$ into $E=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}E_n$ where $E_n=E\bigcap[n-1,n]$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$? Then we have $\{E_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$, a  countable collection of measurable subsets of $E$ and of finite measure since $E_n \subseteq [n-1,n]$ so $m(E_n)\leq 1< \infty$. Also, each pair of $E_n$'s are not necessarily disjoint.

Now, if there is a closed set $F_n \subseteq E_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, this means that the collection $\{F_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ do not have pairwise disjoint sets in it right?

My question might be lacking in motivation, but I was hoping that if my constructions above are true then it might be a remedy in my proof (invalid) on the extension of Lusin's theorem to the case where $m(E)=\infty$ which appears in this post: [Lusin's Theorem when $m(E)=+\infty$. Proof Verification.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704354/lusins-theorem-when-me-infty-proof-verification)

Comment: Presumably you want pairwise disjoint closed $F_n\subset E_n$ such that $\cup_nF_n$ is closed and  $m(E)-m(\cup_nF_n)$ is as small as we like. For any $e\in (0,1),$ for each $n\in Z,$ let $F_{n,e}$ be a closed subset of  $S_{n.e}= [n-1+e 2^{-1-|n|} , n-e 2^{-1-|n|} ]\cap E$ such that  $m(E_n)-m(S_{n,e})<e 2^{-1-|n|}.$

Answer (score 1):

- First question: Yes.  From $E_n \triangleq E \cap [n-1,n]$, it's trivial that $E=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb Z} E_n$.
- Second question: No.  Consider $E = \Bbb R$, then $m(E) = \infty$.  $$E_n \triangleq E \cap [n-1,n] = [n-1,n],$$ so "each pair of $E_n$'s is not necessarily disjoint" (as $E_n \cap E_{n+1} = \{n\}$). $$F_n \triangleq E \bigcap \left [n-\dfrac34,n-\dfrac14 \right] = \left [n-\dfrac34,n-\dfrac14 \right] \subseteq E_n \quad \forall\,n \in \Bbb N,$$  but the collection of closed subsets $\{F_n\}_{n\in \Bbb Z}$ is *pairwise disjoint*: $$F_i \cap F_j = \varnothing \text{ whenever } i \ne j.$$

Comment: I realized that if I'm going to make a non pairwise disjoint collection of a decomposition of $E$, then my current definition of $E_n$'s are too restrictive, how about if I redefine $E_n=E\bigcap [-n,n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Kurome This changes *nothing* of my answer. $$F_n \subseteq E \cap [n-1,n] \subseteq E \cup [-n,n]$$  The collection $\{F_n\}_{n\in \Bbb Z}$ is *still pairwise disjoint*.

Comment: What does the equal sign with the triangle mean?

Comment: It means "defined as".  You may also use $:=$.